# Quickly App Maker for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: quickly

I would like to know where can I download Quickly App Maker for Ubuntu 16.04 because link I am getting is for Ubuntu 13.10.

Any advise will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's "Quickly app maker" ? Could you link to the website / download page ? You could try the 13.10 version and see if it works.

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 16.04 so can't try 13.10. This is the link https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/quickly/ where I tried to download Quickly App maker.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution.

I downloaded and installed four `quickly_12.08.1.deb` built files in Ubuntu 16.04 from: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/12.08.1-0ubuntu2/+build/3854610

The files were:

```
python-quickly-common_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
python-quickly-core_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
quickly-ubuntu-template_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
quickly_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

I installed the four above using `gdebi`.
I also needed `gedit`, `glade` and `glade-gtk2`.

That enables to:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application foobar
quickly run
quickly design
quickly edit
```

**Note:**
You must be in 'foobar' folder to run, design and edit.

To get `quickly package` to run, I had to install these:

```
apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake autotools-dev dh-make debhelper devscripts fakeroot xutils lintian pbuilder
```

It's not pretty, but it works and produces a functioning `.deb` application that can be installed and removed using `gdebi`.

An alternative option:
Run Ubuntu 14.04 in a virtual machine (I used VirtualBox), then load `quickly` as normal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install quickly quickly-ubuntu-template
```

**Note:**
You can then produce a `.deb` package from Ubuntu 14.04 that also works in 16.04 (I used `gdebi` to install and remove them).

**Also:**
I needed to install `vbox-guest-additions` of the same revision as my host app to get full screen resolution.