# How to install quickly?

Tags: 16.04, quickly

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried to install quickly for creating ubuntu apps. But it is saying unable to locate package. I followed the instructions given in this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly and then tried this

```
sudo apt-get install quickly quickly-ubuntu-template
```

but still it is saying unable to locate package quickly. What to do now. Is there any other cool software to build ubuntu apps like quickly?

Comment: quick and dirty solution here:- https://askubuntu.com/questions/767913/quickly-app-maker-for-ubuntu-16-04/1173793#1173793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly is no longer available on any Linux distribution past Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Therefore, it is (unfortunately) uninstallable in newer distributions.

You could use something like [Illumination Software Creator](https://github.com/jsebean/IlluminationSoftwareCreator) to make programs. Alternatively, you can just learn how to program in Java and/or C++, which is slightly more involved than these software creators, but they can create far better results.

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty solution

I downloaded and installed four `quickly_12.08.1.deb` Built files in Ubuntu 16.04 from:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/12.08.1-0ubuntu2/+build/3854610

```
python-quickly-common_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
python-quickly-core_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
quickly-ubuntu-template_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
quickly_12.08.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

I installed the four above using `gdebi`.
I also needed `gedit`, `glade` and `glade-gtk2`

that enables:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application foobar
quickly run
quickly design
quickly edit
```

note: you must be in `foobar` folder to run, design and edit.

to get `quickly package` to run I had to install these:-

```
apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake autotools-dev dh-make debhelper devscripts fakeroot xutils lintian pbuilder
```

it's not pretty but it works and produces functioning `.deb` applications that can be installed and removed using `gdebi`.

---

alternative option:
run Ubuntu 14.04.3 in a virtual machine (I used VirtualBox),then load 'quickly' as normal:-

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install quickly quickly-ubuntu-template
```

Note:
you can then produce a `.deb` package from Ubuntu 14.04 that also works in 16.04 (I used `gdebi` to install and remove them)

Also:
I needed to install `vbox-guest-additions` of the same revision as my host app to get full screen resolution.