# How did quickly run work to run a software from source?

Tags: python3, packaging, quickly

`quickly` used to be a very convenient software which could be used to debian package a new software in minutes, but it [got discontinued](https://askubuntu.com/q/818048/124466).

I have some old python code packaged with quickly, which I have manually ported to Python 3.

While I can package it with `debuild` after doing `dch` (the analogous quickly command was the single command `quickly release x.y`), I don't know how to run it from the source without installing (this could be done with `quickly run`).

What is the equivalent of `quickly run` without using quickly? In other words, how to run [this code](https://github.com/apandada1/Up-Clock) without installing, for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you want, may not work even by restructuring it as flat package. Because, it need glib schemas to be installed and other language/theme/icon files to be in place.
- You may install it as Python package which is quicker then building DEB package.

  ```
  python setup.py sdist
  pip install ./*.tar.gz
  ```